# How does hunter avoid the Machine?

Tags: mutant-chronicles

In Mutant chronicles, Hunter the main character manages to mostly avoid being mutated by the machine. How is it he seems to be the only one to be able to do this? If doesn't seem like he puts much effort into avoid the injections just timing.

Why can no one else do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am remembering correctly most of the people put into the machine were either dead and dying making it so they couldn't really move. Hunter however was injured though not significantly allowing him greater movement.